# How do I make a non-editable field editable in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a field `creation` with `auto_now_add=True` in my model. I want to be able to edit this from the admin website, but when I try to display the field, I get the following error:

```
'creation' cannot be specified for model form as it is a non-editable field
```

I tried adding `editable=True` to the model field as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields), but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields with `auto_now_add=True` are not editable. You need remove the `auto_now_add`, and set a default value or overwrite the model save method to set the creation date.

```py
created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

... or ...

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kw)
        if not self.created:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kw)
```